# Given a filename, Python code that look for the directory of the file?

Tags: python-3.x, directory, path, filepath

I have a server that stores few thousands of images. The link is like this: www.website.com/graphics/"subdirectory"/"filename.jpg".

I'm making a Python program where I must find the file path of a given file name. For example, giving the input is a filename = "fish.jpg". The file is located in "animal" subdirectory, so the file path is www.website.com/graphics/animal/fish.jpg

In other words, the input is "fish.jpg" and the output must be "www.website.com/graphics/animal/fish.jpg". All images are in "www.website.com/graphics". Subdirectory "animal" is not known and is what I'm looking for.

Thank you for reading my post. Looking forward to your answering soon.

Comment: Are these all local files? What have you tried?

Comment: these are not local files, that why it is so hard. All files are on the server, live website.

Comment: It depends on how you access the server. SSH, or some other protocols.